# FFmpeg: Pipe segments to s3

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, pipe, aws-cli

I'd like to pipe ffmpeg segments to s3 without writing them to disk.

```
ffmpeg -i t2.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 20 output_%04d.mkv
```

Is it possible to modify this command so that ffmpeg writes segments to an s3 bucket? Something like this perhaps?

```
ffmpeg -i t2.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 20 pipe:1 \
  | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/output_%04d.mkv
```

When I run the command above I receive this error

```
Could not write header for output file #0
(incorrect codec parameters ?): Muxer not found
```

This command works except the entire video is uploaded and not the individual segments

```
ffmpeg -i t2.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 20 pipe:output_%04d.mkv \
| aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/test.mkv
```

Comment: Which linux of Linux are you running this on?

Answer (score 3):

It works with s3fs. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

s3fs version:

```
root@ip-172-31-69-62:~# s3fs --version
Amazon Simple Storage Service File System V1.86 (commit:unknown) with OpenSSL
Copyright (C) 2010 Randy Rizun <rrizun@gmail.com>
License GPL2: GNU GPL version 2 <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
root@ip-172-31-69-62:~#
```

Compiled from source; could never get it to work with regular version installed from 'apt install s3fs'. You need to have .aws/credentials properly configured and then just mount a folder:

```
root@ip-172-31-69-62:~# s3fs sm-alfa-beta /mnt/s5
```

Don't pipe it; treat it as a regular folder and it lands on the S3 bucket.

```
root@ip-172-31-69-62:~# ffmpeg -i t2.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 5 /mnt/s5/output_%04d.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 't2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2014-07-18T06:00:15.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:21.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14904 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14517 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-18T06:00:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-18T06:00:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
[segment @ 0x55e4b1d6d660] Opening '/mnt/s5/output_0000.mkv' for writing
Output #0, segment, to '/mnt/s5/output_%04d.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 14517 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-18T06:00:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-07-18T06:00:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[segment @ 0x55e4b1d6d660] Opening '/mnt/s5/output_0001.mkv' for writing
[segment @ 0x55e4b1d6d660] Opening '/mnt/s5/output_0002.mkv' for writing
[segment @ 0x55e4b1d6d660] Opening '/mnt/s5/output_0003.mkv' for writing1.9x    
[segment @ 0x55e4b1d6d660] Opening '/mnt/s5/output_0004.mkv' for writing1.2x    
frame=  531 fps=284 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:21.22 bitrate=N/A speed=11.4x    
video:37640kB audio:491kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Here are the segments:

```
root@ip-172-31-69-62:~# ls -l /mnt/s5
total 38150
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9542771 Jul  7 20:01 output_0000.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9464801 Jul  7 20:01 output_0001.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10072341 Jul  7 20:01 output_0002.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8269715 Jul  7 20:01 output_0003.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1714287 Jul  7 20:01 output_0004.mkv
root@ip-172-31-69-62:~#
```

Instructions to compile s3fs on Ubuntu 18.04.4:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libfuse-dev automake

cd /tmp && \
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git && \
cd s3fs-fuse && \
./autogen.sh && \
./configure  && \
make

sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to work with S3 like it is an ordinary filesystem.

Comment: Can you provide an example how s3fs can work with piping multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `aws s3` supports piping multiple files from stdin, either with `ffmpeg` or any other command. Looking at the [cli docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) I see no mention of a protocol over stdin that would support that. Even if such a scheme existed it would be pretty fiddly to work with; the stream would presumably have to include the length of the files to upload or use some sort of complex spec to encode the separate file contents within a single stream of data, and there's no reason to believe it would be compatible with `ffmpeg`.

If your goal is to avoid writing to physical disks, I'd suggest trying to create the files you need in memory, using a memory-backed filesystem like [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs). The benefit of this approach is you don't need to do anything special with the individual programs (`ffmpeg` and `aws s3`), they interact with the filesystem as normal but the data is actually only written to RAM.

If that's not an option, I'd step back once more and consider how problematic these disk writes really are. The filesystem is, by design, how files are represented, so if you're trying to upload several files to AWS the filesystem may well be the best option. Are you sure your disks are really the bottleneck you need to address? Otherwise you may need to look for an alternative to the `ffmpeg` command line tool that will allow you to generate the segments you need in memory and stream them directly to S3. You may need to build such a utility yourself.

Comment: Aws lamda limits the file system to 500MB, so it’s easily a bottleneck there

Comment: @Tom that's a fair point, but I don't think that you'll be able to avoid the file system with `ffmpeg` + `aws s3`. A dedicated segment-and-upload binary would presumably work, but would probably have to be hand-made.

Answer (score 0):

`aws s3 cp` does not (yet) support piping of **multiple files**.

So you will have to save these multiple files locally first, and then `cp` them as a whole folder with `--recursive` (as you've mentioned in your question), or one by one.