# 503 Slow Down when uploading to S3 with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm uploading many small file to S3 using Rails and Carrierwave in a background job, and am hitting S3 rate limits. My immediate thought is to put a `sleep 0.1` before each upload, but that doesn't seem like a great solution.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this via the S3 API and some type of backoff?

Ruby code that is doing the upload, this method is called in a loop thousands of times:

```rb
    def attach_audio(object:, audio_field:, attachment:)
      return true if Rails.env.test?

      language_code, voice_id = language_and_voice(object)

      resp = polly.synthesize_speech(
        output_format: 'mp3',
        voice_id: voice_id,
        text: audio_field.to_s,
        language_code: language_code
      )

      audio_filename = "#{object.class.to_s.downcase}_#{attachment}_#{object.id}_#{voice_id}.mp3"
      audio_path = "#{Rails.root}/db/audio/#{audio_filename}"
      IO.copy_stream(resp.audio_stream, audio_path)

      object.send(attachment + '=', Pathname.new(audio_path).open)
      object.save!
    end
```

Uploader class

```rb
class AudioUploader < BaseUploader

  def store_dir
    "uploads/audio/#{model.target_language}/#{self.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w[mp3]
  end
end
```

```rb
class BaseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  if Rails.env.test?
    storage :file
  else
    storage :fog
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{self.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Response from AWS

```
Message

Excon::Error::ServiceUnavailable: Expected(200) <=> Actual(503 Service Unavailable) excon.error.response :body => "<Error><Code>SlowDown</Code><Message>Please reduce your request rate.</Message><RequestId>176C22715A856A29</RequestId><HostId>L/+

Traceback

Excon::Error::ServiceUnavailable: Expected(200) <=> Actual(503 Service Unavailable)
excon.error.response
  :body          => "<Error><Code>SlowDown</Code><Message>Please reduce your request rate.</Message><RequestId>176C22715A856A29</RequestId><HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId></Error>"
  :cookies       => [
  ]
  :headers       => {
    "Connection"       => "close"
    "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
    "Date"             => "Wed, 18 Nov 2020 07:31:29 GMT"
    "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
    "x-amz-id-2"       => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "x-amz-request-id" => "176C22715A856A29"
  }
  :host          => "example-production.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
  :local_address => "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"
  :local_port    => 50276
  :path          => "/uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423/word_audio_file_8015423_Mathieu.mp3"
  :port          => 443
  :reason_phrase => "Slow Down"
  :remote_ip     => "xx.xxx.xx.x"
  :status        => 503
  :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 503 Slow Down\r\n"

  File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/excon-0.71.1/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb", line 13, in response_call
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/excon-0.71.1/lib/excon/middlewares/response_parser.rb", line 12, in response_call
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/excon-0.71.1/lib/excon/connection.rb", line 448, in response
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/excon-0.71.1/lib/excon/connection.rb", line 279, in request
  File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/fog-xml-0.1.3/lib/fog/xml/sax_parser_connection.rb", line 35, in request

etc
```

**EDIT**

The linked AWS documentation refers to prefixes, which would seem to solve the problem

> Amazon S3 automatically scales to high request rates. For example, your application can achieve at least 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in a bucket. There are no limits to the number of prefixes in a bucket. You can increase your read or write performance by parallelizing reads. For example, if you create 10 prefixes in an Amazon S3 bucket to parallelize reads, you could scale your read performance to 55,000 read requests per second.

But I don't understand how to implement it in the context of Carrierwave.

Comment: There seems to be some solution in the form of prefixes, but I don't really understand the article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: So how many uploads per second you think you have? Do you use Sidekiq or ActiveJob?

Comment: If you read aws documentation they suggest using an exponential backoff if you start getting slow down response https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html. I'm not too familiar with these libraries but I reckon you could rescue the error, parse the body for the AWS error code and then wait for (2^retry_count) seconds before trying again

Comment: Could s3fs be the answer? Instead of uploading you would be writing to a s3fs mounted partition with the end result being the same. You can see my answer to a somewhat similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311166/ffmpeg-pipe-segments-to-s3/62783203#62783203

Comment: Like Hubert asked: How many parallel uploads to you have running? I've used S3 for years and I'ver never hit their limits ...

Comment: Could be 5000 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using https://github.com/nickelser/activejob-traffic_control, but couldn't get the job to work properly.

In the end I found a super-simple solution that worked: I moved the audio creation and storage in S3 for each word into a new ActiveJob class. Then just called it 1000s of times, and it is automatically throttled by the Sidekiq concurrency settings.

config/sidekiq.yml

```yaml
---
:concurrency: 10
:max_retries: 3
:queues:
  - [urgent, 4]
  - [nlp, 3]
  - [default, 2]
  - [low]
```

Answer (score 6):

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html)

> For example, your application can achieve at least 3,500
> PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix
> in a bucket.

you learn what your limits are. Now you need to understand what a ***prefix*** is and that's easy. Consider this:

> /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423/word_audio_file_8015423_Mathieu.mp3

What is the ***prefix*** here? Answer:

> /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423

The ***prefix*** is everything except the object name. So the answer to your problem resides in your hability to design a scheme so that you never exceed the limits defined by Amazon for each ***prefix***.

You could for example use a *revolving counter*, let's say from 0 to 99, and store somewhere the relationship between the object being saved and the *revolving counter spot* where it was stored [so that you can read it later]. If you were to implement this, your problem would be reduced to 1/100th of what it is right now; you may actually not need to go all the way to 100 and you could always increase it in the future if you needed to. So now, this:

> /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423/word_audio_file_8015423_Mathieu.mp3

would be stored in:

> /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/**00**/8015423/word_audio_file_8015423_Mathieu.mp3

and the next one in **.../01/...** so on and so forth, with the 100th object stored in **.../99/...** and then the 101st object stored back in **.../00/...** [you wouldn't have to use the two characters obviously].

The extra step this process brings to your logic is that for retrieval purposes you need to know that *word_audio_file_8015423_Mathieu.mp3* is in **.../00/...** and, for example, *word_audio_file_8015424_Mark.mp3* is in **.../01/...** and so on. This means you would have to store the relationship between the object and the spot where it was saved. On the other hand, you may not even need to do that if it's acceptable to search all the spots looking for the object you want.

I feel strongly this would take care of your problem.

Comment: This is very helpful: "The prefix is everything except the object name". I still need to work out how to change the Uploader class to do this automatically.

Comment: If the prefix is "/uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423", the last part (8015423) is the database ID, so it will always be unique. I would think this means the prefix is unique also?

Comment: Are you saying that you are making only one upload to each folder? If you browse folder /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423 there is only one file there?

Comment: The AWS message makes perfect sense. You are hitting the prefix /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/ at a rate that exceeds the limits. You see, /uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/ is the prefix for all the database IDs and you are creating database IDs at a very fast rate. I feel the solution I propose will work and worst case scenario you can parallelize even more than 100; you could go to 1000 if 100 still gives a 503 error.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Sidekiq without ActiveJob you could use [sidekiq-throttled](https://github.com/sensortower/sidekiq-throttled) gem and threshold option to slow down your uploads in background jobs.

Example:

```
class UploadWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Throttled::Worker

  sidekiq_options :queue => :uploads
  sidekiq_throttle({
    # Allow maximum 1K jobs being processed within one second window.
    :threshold => { :limit => 1_000, :period => 1.second }
  })

  def perform
    # do your thing
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I was wondering what the S3 documentation means by prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glos-chap.html#keyprefix) **prefix** aka **key prefix** is similar to a directory name that enables you to store similar data under the same directory in a bucket. You need to find your way how you could group your uploads. In your case it could be making additional directory from `object.id` value as a name.

Comment: Thank you, this is already the case: "/uploads/audio/fr/audio_uploader/word/audio_file/8015423/word_audio_file_8015423_Mathieu.mp3", see also: "    "uploads/audio/#{model.target_language}/#{self.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"

Comment: Ups, sorry I didn't notice. I thought that's the fix according to docs.